# Moving from Swing to Web Applications

Tags: java, swing, web

I am decent (or so I like to think) when it comes to making java swing applications, but I want to make the jump to web applications.

The problem lies with the fact that there's so much going on and so much different terminology being thrown around. I have no idea where to begin and it seems very daunting.

I've read up on a few things such as JSP and GWT, but I still can't seem to be able to make the jump. My question is: is there a specific flow used when making a web application to make everything seem to connect better, and if possible, could you recommend a good starting point for someone like me that comes from a solely desktop gui environment and wants to start developing web apps? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Both Swing and Web application still rely upon java keywords and terminology. java web technology work better when you use a framework . I suggest you start with Spring. It has MVC library that you can use, plus spring mvc has a large community online. However, Java Servlet is quite similar with what you have learn in java.